# Open wxDialog trough Event and add a panel to it

Tags: wxwidgets

I try (since 4 days) to open a wxDialog (declared in a own Class)trough ClickOnEvent aon a menuitem.

I've managed that I get a empty wxDialog an to open it Nonmodal, so I can use the MainFrame at the same time.

But when I try to add a panel to the wxDialog but got a error:

***error: cannot call constructor 'SideFrame::SideFrame' directly [-fpermissive]***

```
void MainFrame::f_SF2(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
  SideFrame::SideFrame("SF2")
       : wxDialog(NULL, -1, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 230))
  {
    sf_p = new wxPanel(this, -1);

    wxColour col1;
    col1.Set(_T("#000000"));

    sf_p->SetBackgroundColour(col1);

    sf2->Show();
  }
}
```

When I try it like below, I get a other error:

***undefined reference to `SideFrame::SideFrame(wxString const&)'***

```
void MainFrame::f_SF2(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
SideFrame *sf2 = new SideFrame(_T("SF2"));


  wxPanel *sf_p = new wxPanel(sf2);

  wxColour col1;
  col1.Set(_T("#000000"));

  sf_p->SetBackgroundColour(col1);

  sf2->Show();
}
```

Can somebody help me, and say how I've to do that?
I`m using wxWidgets 2.9.4 and the g++-compiler

Answer (score 0):

1. ctor shall not be called directly in C++. Use operator `new` instead.
2. Check the signature of your `SideFrame::SideFrame`.

Below is an example that may help.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class SideFrame : public wxDialog
{
public:
    SideFrame(wxString sTitle) : wxDialog(NULL, wxID_ANY, sTitle) {}
protected:
    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent &) {
        this->Destroy(); // Ask wxWidgets to `delete this;`
    }
private:
wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(SideFrame, wxDialog)
    EVT_CLOSE(SideFrame::OnClose)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class CApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() {
        wxFrame * frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "demo");
        // Double click the main frame to create a modeless dialog.
        frame->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DCLICK, [](wxMouseEvent &)->void{
            // Create and display a modeless dialog.
            SideFrame * sf2 = new SideFrame("untitled"); // Note, a modeless dialog MUST be dynamically-allocated.
            (new wxPanel(sf2))->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour("#000000"));
            sf2->Show(true);
        });
        frame->Show(true);
        return this->wxApp::OnInit();
    }
};
DECLARE_APP(CApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(CApp)
```

Note how a modeless dialog is to be created and deleted. Usually we create it like an ordinary dynamic object, and then deallocate it in a suitable handling method where we shall `this->Destroy();`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your Example don't run for me,
I got the error:
_error: no matching function for call to 'wxFrame::Bind(const wxEventTypeTag<wxMouseEvent>&, CApp::OnInit()::<lambda(wxMouseEvent&)>)_

Comment: Thanks Men (or Women), you save my Life. I try a bit out and now its run for me (I edited a little bit your example, and now my Panel has a Name and a static text in it).

You are a very big help!